# In the OSGi eco-system landscape is there any mean to automatically upgrade the OSGi Container himself?

Tags: osgi, upgrade

Maybe this question seems odd ?
I am working on *OSGi-fication* of our software based on Agents collecting some informations on servers.

Concerning Bundles update, it's natively supported by OSGi frameworks (OBR, Apache ACE, ...)
But, concerning the OSGI Container itself (Felix, Karaf, ...), is there a mechanism or a framework/tool having capacity to upgrade the container "automatically"?

Any idea? Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Not in the OSGi specification. It assumes the framework is available on the classpath and can be launched. Any ability to update the framework implementation would be specific to a framework implementation as a value add.

Comment: Thx, BJ, for this enlightenment.